# What is the analytical closed-form solution of the two-body problem to verify its numerical integration results?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, orbit, trajectory, celestial-mechanics

The purpose is to study the motion of two celestial bodies analytically. What is the closed-form of the two-body problem if I was to solve it analytically without using a numerical approximation technique.

An example where this would be useful is this question from the book *[Analytical Mechanics of Space Systems](https://arc.aiaa.org/doi/book/10.2514/4.105210)* by Hanspeter Schaub.

> Write a numerical simulation that integrates the differential equations of motion in Eq. (9.45) using a fourth-order Runge Kutta integration scheme. Using the subroutine of task (b), compare the answer of the numerical integration to the analytical two-body solution.
>
> $$\mathbf{\ddot{r}}=-\frac{\mu}{r^3}\mathbf{r} = -\frac{\mu}{r^2}\mathbf{\hat{r}}  \tag{9.45}$$

Comment: Not going to type up an answer right now, but this exact question is answered in -- well -- pretty much every single orbital mechanics textbook out there.

Comment: What do you miss in [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-body_problem) Wikipedia article? See also the links to other articles there.

Comment: @Uwe What I miss is how is the transformation of the set of elements to find the motion of a planet in arbitrary reference frame.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a supplemental answer for now because [while we know](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-body_problem#Reduction_to_two_independent,_one-body_problems) that a two body orbit can be reduced to a one body orbit around a central potential, doing that here will be a little distracting and I think the result for the one body in central potential looks cleaner. See also answers to [Can the radial oscillations of an elliptical orbit be solved using a fictitious centrifugal potential?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/518913/83380)

---

Per [this comment](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/43213/what-is-the-analytical-closed-form-solution-of-the-two-body-problem/43217?noredirect=1#comment139277_43217) I know I've had a discussion somewhere in this site (or in [Astronomy SE](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/)) where it was first explained to me that Kepler orbits do have *analytical solutions* you can write down for *time as a function of position*, even though we still do need to use numerical techniques (e.g. Newton's method) to solve position as a function of time. (see also [How did Newton and Kepler (actually) do it?](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/q/3575/3869))

If someone finds it before I do *please feel free to add a link here, thanks!*

Equation 27 in Wikipedia's [Kepler orbit; Properties of trajectory equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler_orbit#Properties_of_trajectory_equation) is

$$t = a \sqrt{\frac{a}{\mu}}\left(E - e \sin E \right)$$

where $a$ is the semimajor axis, $\mu$ is the [standard gravitational parameter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_gravitational_parameter) also known as the product $GM$, $e$ is the eccentricity and $E$ is the [Eccentric anomaly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eccentric_anomaly).

[The relationship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eccentric_anomaly) between $E$ and the [true anomaly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/True_anomaly) $\theta = \arctan2(y, x)$ is

$$\tan \frac{\theta}{2} = \sqrt{ \frac{1+e}{1-e} } \tan \frac{E}{2}$$

and solving for $E$:

$$E(\theta) = 2 \arctan \sqrt{ \frac{1-e}{1+e} } \tan \frac{\theta}{2}.$$

plugging back in to the first equation (but not writing it all out):

$$t(\theta) = a \sqrt{\frac{a}{\mu}}\left(E(\theta) - e \sin E(\theta) \right)$$

Let's try a numerical check of this amazing result. Note that with $a=1$ and $\mu=1$ the period is $2 \pi$.

The last plot at bottom left shows that the analytical $t(\theta)$ based on $\theta$ from a numerically integrated orbit matches the time used in the numerical calculation for an $e=0.8$ elliptical orbit. There will be numerical glitches or singularities at the endpoints and for $e=1$ but it seems to check out nicely!

[image: numerical integration of e=0.8 elliptical orbit]

[image: check of analytical t(theta) against numerical integration of e=0.8 elliptical orbit]

Python script:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import odeint as ODEint

def deriv(X, t):
    x, v = X.reshape(2, -1)
    acc = -x * ((x**2).sum())**-1.5
    return np.hstack((v, acc))

halfpi, pi, twopi = [f*np.pi for f in (0.5, 1, 2)]

e = 0.8
a = 1.0
mu = 1.0
r_peri, r_apo = a*(1.-e), a*(1.+e)
v_peri, v_apo = [np.sqrt(2./r - 1./a) for r in (r_peri, r_apo)]
T = twopi * np.sqrt(a**3/mu)

X0 = np.array([r_peri, 0, 0, v_peri])
X0 = np.array([-r_apo, 0, 0, -v_apo])
times = np.linspace(-T/2., T/2., 1001)

answer, info = ODEint(deriv, X0, times, full_output=True)

x, y = answer[1:-1].T[:2]
theta = np.arctan2(y, x)
E = 2. * np.arctan(np.sqrt((1.-e)/(1.+e)) * np.tan(theta/2))
t = a * np.sqrt(a/mu) * (E - e * np.sin(E))

if True:
    plt.figure()
    plt.subplot(2, 1, 1)
    plt.plot(x, y)
    plt.plot([0], [0], 'ok')
    plt.gca().set_aspect('equal')
    plt.title('y vs. x numerical')
    plt.subplot(2, 1, 2)
    plt.plot(times[1:-1], x)
    plt.plot(times[1:-1], y)
    plt.xlim(-pi, pi)
    plt.title('x(t) and y(t) numerical')
    plt.show()

    plt.subplot(2, 2, 1)
    plt.title('theta(t_numerical)')
    plt.plot(times[1:-1], theta)
    plt.xlim(-pi, pi)
    plt.ylim(-pi, pi)
    plt.gca().set_aspect('equal')
    plt.subplot(2, 2, 2)
    plt.title('E_analytic(theta_numerical)')
    plt.plot(E, theta)
    plt.xlim(-pi, pi)
    plt.ylim(-pi, pi)
    plt.gca().set_aspect('equal')
    plt.subplot(2, 2, 3)
    plt.title('theta(t_analytic)')
    plt.plot(t, theta)
    plt.xlim(-pi, pi)
    plt.ylim(-pi, pi)
    plt.gca().set_aspect('equal')
    plt.subplot(2, 2, 4)
    plt.title('t_analytic(t_numerical)')
    plt.plot(t, times[1:-1])
    plt.xlim(-pi, pi)
    plt.ylim(-pi, pi)
    plt.gca().set_aspect('equal')
    plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you for this very informative answer! I just have one small question that might be silly; I see that you used the ODE45 to integrate the orbit of the two-body problem. How do you verify that the orbit is correct using the analytical solution of the problem?

Comment: I have updated this post with an image clarifying what I mean by my previous comment.

Comment: @John First a note: for the numerical integration I used [SciPy's odeint](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.odeint.html) which chooses between "1: adams (nonstiff), 2: bdf (stiff)" for the integration method" I don't know how it compares to MatLab's [ODE45](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ode45.html) but for such an easy nonstiff problem like this I think any integrator will give good results. There is also a method called **RK45** https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%E2%80%93Kutta%E2%80%93Fehlberg_method#Butcher_tableau_for_Fehlberg's_4(5)_method

Comment: @John now on to your question about your question and its clarification; So far we don't know what "the analytical two-body solution" is exactly, whether it's $r(\theta)$ shown in [the other answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/43217/12102) or also includes $t(\theta)$ as I'm shown here. You show a small snipped from a screen shot only. This is not the best way to ask a Stack Exchange question, revealing small bits at a time. If you can share more about what exactly you are given then others will have a better time addressing how to proceed. But I would guess they mean to compare outputs.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The reason I did not post the rest of the question because it is irrelevant. Part a) and b) are related to transform the classical orbital elements to Cartesian orbital position and vice-versa. However, no analytical solution is provided or either asked to be derived (I think the author assumes we already know it). I have updated the question by adding Eq. (9.45) which he refers too. I hope its clearer now and apologies for any misunderstanding.

Comment: @John I updated your question; it's discouraged to use screen-shots of text, we should take the time to type them. One reason is that sight-impaired people can use other tools to read text but a screenshot is useless. I added the equation using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/284619) and you will see that the 2nd form is what I used in my numerical integration. I'm not exactly sure what else you need answered, please feel free to continue the discussion here! I do wonder what "task (b)" refers to in the quoted text though.

Comment: I wasn't aware of that, thanks for pointing it out. Will make sure to follow. What I meant was that assuming we numerically integrated equation 9.45 and got some nice orbit plots. How can I verify those plots are correct by using the analytical solution of the equation? and what would the analytical form be like?

Comment: @John I can't read the author's mind and I don't have a copy of the book handy this weekend to read it. My last equation is *an analytical solution* though it's for $t(\theta)$ rather than for $\theta(t)$, the other answer shows *an analytical solution* for $r(\theta)$ though not $r(t)$, but without reading the text how can *I tell you* what the author means by "the analytical two-body solution"? This answer compares its analytical solution with its numerical solution in the last plot. I could also plot $r_{numerical}$ vs $\theta_{numerical}$ and compare it to

Comment: @John the expression in the other answer. But is that what the author of the book is describing? From your tiny snippet I can't tell. I think this is as far as I can go here, maybe someone else can add another answer. You'll have to read further to know how to apply a one-body solution to a two-body problem, as I've mentioned in my answer.

Comment: Got it! Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 3):

The distance from the focus of attraction of an orbit can be expressed as a function of the true anomaly (an angular value) given by $r(\theta)=a\frac{1-e^2}{1+e\cos(\theta)}$, where $a$ is the semi-major axis and $e$ is the eccentricity.

Comment: How is the second mass affecting the first mass based on gravitational attraction in this equation?

Comment: Answers to [Can the radial oscillations of an elliptical orbit be solved using a fictitious centrifugal potential?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/518913/83380) also contain some helpful information.

Comment: Is it possible to show $t(\theta)$ as well?

Comment: @John: The reference frame is fixed to one of the two masses (usually the larger one).  In this reference frame, one mass observes the other mass rotating around it as if the first mass were motionless.  Both objects exert forces on each other, but the reference frame makes it appear as if only one mass were moving with respect to the other.

Comment: @uhoh:  Time as a function of true anomaly?  Perhaps you mean true anomaly as a function of time? Or perhaps time between two anomalies?

Comment: @Paul From what I remember $t(\theta)$ has an actual analytical solution, but $\theta(t)$ does not. My memory comes from a discussion somewhere in this site a few years ago, I'll try to look for it now. For starters, scroll down to [Equation 27](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler_orbit#Properties_of_trajectory_equation). That's eccentric anomaly $E$ but it's a start.

Comment: Since I've always wanted to try this I went ahead and wrote it up [here](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/43237/12102).