# Calculate Satellite ground track

Tags: orbital-mechanics, earth, ground-track

I'm trying to find equations to calculate satellite position based on orbit parameters and given time. What I currently have is a mess that is basically giving me bunch of garbage.

**What is latitude and longitude for any reasonable orbit parameters?**

Comment: When you say "orbit parameters" it could be several different things. Could you show what parameters you are working with? The calculation isn't short and requires piecing together information from several existing answers here. For example even for a simple elliptical orbit there is no analytical expression (equation) for position as a function of time (though there is for time as a function of position).

Comment: See for example [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/43237/12102)

Comment: If you want to have this very precise, you need to take Earth Orientation Parameters and different Frames into account. Do you really need to calculate this "on paper" or do you need a software able to do this, or maybe just source code for this problem?

Comment: If you like Python then Skyfield's [`.subpoint()`](https://rhodesmill.org/skyfield/api-position.html#skyfield.positionlib.Geocentric.subpoint) method will work for any planets, the Sun and Moon and a variety of other astronomical objects, including artificial satellites whose orbits are determined by TLEs.

Comment: DId you find a solution? If so, it's always okay to post a (reasonable) answer to your own question.