# How to calculate the velocity vector in the case of a hyperbolic orbit?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, velocity

### The problem

I'm trying to get a formula to calculate the state vectors $\vec{r}$ and
$\vec{v} = \dot{\vec{r}}$ on an orbit, given a true anomaly $\nu$. I'm following the process described here : https://downloads.rene-schwarz.com/download/M001-Keplerian_Orbit_Elements_to_Cartesian_State_Vectors.pdf . The first calculation step involves calculating the intermediate simple state vectors $\vec{o}$ and $\dot{\vec{o}}$ laying in the xy plane (which are then rotated in space to get $\vec{r}$ and $\vec{v}$ respectively) :

$$
\vec{o} = r\left(\begin{array}{ c }
\cos \nu\\
\sin \nu \\
0
\end{array}\right), \ \
\dot{\vec{o}} = \frac{\sqrt{\mu a}}{r}\left(\begin{array}{ c }
-\sin E\\
\sqrt{1-e^{2}}\cos E\\
0
\end{array}\right)
$$

with $r = \dfrac{p}{1+e\cos\nu}$.

This works well in the case of an elliptic orbit, but it is invalid for a hyperbolic one because of $e > 1$ and $a < 0$ resulting in $\sqrt{1-e^2}$ and $\sqrt{\mu a}$ being undefined.

### My current solution

In the case of an hyperbolic orbit, I adapted the second answer from this post : [Calculating velocity state vector with orbital elements in 2D](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/22172/calculating-velocity-state-vector-with-orbital-elements-in-2d) to calculate $\dot{\vec{o}}$
with the flight path angle $\phi$, knowing the angular momentum $h = ||\vec{h}||$. We first calculate the radial unit vector $\hat{u_o}$ of the intermediate position vector, and $\hat{u_s}$
the unit vector perpendicular to $\hat{u_o}$ in the xy plane :

$$
\hat{u_o} = \frac{\vec{o}}{r} = 
\left(\begin{array}{ c }
u_{o,\ x}\\
u_{o,\ y}\\
0
\end{array}\right)
, \ \ \hat{u_s} =
\left(\begin{array}{ c }
-u_{o,\ y}\\
u_{o,\ x}\\
0
\end{array}\right)
$$

We then calculate the sin and cos of the flight path angle :
$$
\cos \phi = \frac{h}{rv}, \ \ \sin \phi = \frac{e \sin \nu}{1 + e \cos \nu} \cos \phi
$$

with $v$ being the magnitude of the velocity, calculated from the *vis-viva equation*. And finally, we get the intermediate velocity vector :

$$
\dot{\vec{o}} = v(\sin(\phi)\hat{u_o} + \cos(\phi)\hat{u_s})
$$

### A better solution ?

Is there a better, more straightforward way, to compute this intermediate velocity vector in the case of a hyperbolic orbit ? One that doesn't require knowing $h$. For example, is there a formula similar to the one given in the PDF that makes use of the hyperbolic eccentric anomaly $H$ ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There maybe something helpful on these pages: [What is hyperbolic eccentric anomaly F?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/27602/12102) and [Are hyperbolic trigonometric functions used to calculate hyperbolic orbits?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/41797/12102)

Comment: @uhoh Thanks for your comment ! I worked out the maths a bit deeper and actually found a solution. I'll describe it in an answer very soon.

Comment: that's excellent!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Solution for hyperbolic velocity

After some mathematical manipulations I ended up finding an actual solution that makes use of the hyperbolic anomaly $H$.

In the following, $e$ is the eccentricity of the orbit, $\nu$ is the true anomaly and
$a$ is the semi major axis.

### Prerequisite : proving that $iH = E$ in a hyperbolic orbit

This little proof is here just to show how one can retrieve the equality from the well known formulas of eccentric anomalies.

- For an elliptical orbit ($e < 1$), the eccentric anomaly $E$ is defined by:
  $$
  \tag{1}
  \tan\frac{E}{2} =\sqrt{\frac{1-e}{1+e}}\tan\frac{\nu }{2}
  $$
- For a hyperbolic orbit ($e > 1$), the hyperbolic anomaly $H$ (also written $F$) is defined by:
  $$
  \tag{2}
  \tanh\frac{H}{2} =\sqrt{\frac{e-1}{e+1}}\tan\frac{\nu }{2}
  $$

In the case of a hyperbolic orbit, $1-e < 0$ leads to an undefined definition of $E$
in (1) because of the square root term. Thus the need to use its hyperbolic equivalent (2).
However, considering the relation (1) in $\mathbb{C}$ by involving $i = \sqrt{-1}$ allows for a complex definition of $E$ :

$$
\tan\frac{E}{2} = i\sqrt{\frac{e-1}{e+1}}\tan\frac{\nu }{2}
$$

in which we notice the right term of (2). This actually directly links $E \in \mathbb{C}$ and $H \in \mathbb{R}$ by:

$$
\tag{3}
\tan\frac{E}{2} = i\tanh\frac{H}{2}
$$

The [relations between hyperbolic and trigonometric functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_functions#Hyperbolic_functions_for_complex_numbers)
give :
$$
\forall x \in \mathbb{R} \ \ \ i\tanh(x) = \tan(ix)
$$

which when applied to (3) leads to:

$$
\tan\frac{E}{2} = \tan\frac{iH}{2}
$$

And since $x \mapsto \tan(ix)$ is bijective $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$ because
it is proportional to $x \mapsto \tanh(x)$, we deduce that :

$$
\tag{4}
iH = E
$$

in the case of a hyperbolic orbit, with $H \in \mathbb{R}$ (and therefore $E \in i\mathbb{R}$).

### Adapting the intermediate velocity vector formula to hyperbolic orbits

The [equation described by René Schwarz](https://downloads.rene-schwarz.com/download/M001-Keplerian_Orbit_Elements_to_Cartesian_State_Vectors.pdf)
to calculate the intermediate velocity vector (ignoring the z-component with value 0) is:

$$
\tag{5}
\dot{\vec{o}} =\frac{\sqrt{\mu a}}{r}\left(\begin{array}{ c }
-\sin E\\
\sqrt{1-e^{2}}\cos E
\end{array}\right)
$$

We suppose now a hyperbolic orbit, therefore $e > 1$ and $a < 0$. Thus (5) cannot be
used directly because $\sqrt{1-e^2}$ and $\sqrt{\mu a}$ are undefined in $\mathbb{R}$.
By using the fact that $a = -|a|$ and $1 - e^2 = -(e^2 - 1)$, considering
the equation in $\mathbb{C}$ gives:

$$
\begin{array}{ c c l }
 ( 5) \ \ \Leftrightarrow \ \ \dot{\vec{o}} & = & \dfrac{\sqrt{-\mu |a|}}{r}\left(\begin{array}{ c }
  -\sin E\\
  \sqrt{-\left( e^{2} -1\right)}\cos E
 \end{array}\right)\\
 & = & i\dfrac{\sqrt{\mu |a|}}{r}\left(\begin{array}{ c }
  -\sin E\\
  i\sqrt{e^{2} -1}\cos E
 \end{array}\right)\\
 & = & \dfrac{\sqrt{\mu |a|}}{r}\left(\begin{array}{ c }
  -i\sin E\\
  -\sqrt{e^{2} -1}\cos E
 \end{array}\right)\\
 & = & \dfrac{\sqrt{\mu |a|}}{r}\left(\begin{array}{ c }
  -\sinh iE\\
  -\sqrt{e^{2} -1}\cosh iE
 \end{array}\right)
\end{array}
$$

because $\forall x \in \mathbb{R} \ \
i\sin x = \sinh ix$ and $\cos x = \cosh ix$.
Finally, involving $iH = E \Leftrightarrow iE = -H$, and the fact that $\cosh$ is *even* and $\sinh$ is *odd*, we get:

$$
\tag{6}
\dot{\vec{o}} =\frac{\sqrt{-\mu a}}{r}\left(\begin{array}{ c }
\sinh H\\
-\sqrt{e^{2} -1}\cosh H
\end{array}\right)
$$

with $|a|$ written as $-a$ for clarity.

This formula seems to work in practical cases (orbit simulation and determination). Please don't hesitate to comment to correct eventual errors.